# I need to make sure that only certain characters are in a list?

Tags: python, regex, string, list, python-2.7

I have this to get input and put it in a list:

```
def start():
    move_order=[raw_input("Enter your moves: ").split()]
```

And I only want the characters A, D, S, C, H (it's for a game >_>) to be allowed. I've tried using the regular expressions stuff:

```
if re.match('[ADSCH]+', [move_order]) is False:
    print "That's not a proper move!"
    return start()
```

...in different forms...

```
string_test=re.compile('[ADSCH]+')
    if string_test.match(move_order]) is False:
        print "That's not a proper move!"
        return start()
```

Aaaaand can't get it to work. I'm definitely doing something wrong within those code blocks, I tried to figure it out, but it's not working. Learning what I'm doing wrong would be nice, but the solution to my problem would teach me a lot more I feel like. I might not even need to use re, but it seemed to me that that was a space efficient way to accomplish what I want. My immediate problem I think is that I don't know how to get the re to use lists (unless (certainly) there's other glaring problems trained eyes can find).

I'll go ahead and ask since I'll probably screw this up too, but I also need to have it make sure that a C is never after an H... but a tiny hint for that would be acceptable because I like figuring things out.

Comment: You send a list to `re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)`, and is it case sensitive?  What kind of items in `move_order` is acceptable, a single char(i.e. ['A', 'S', 'D'])?

Comment: I suppose not case sensitive. Well the user would ideally give input like:
A A S D C H D or D C A S A D H or etc (Seven single characters, only rules are that there can only be one H and one S and C can't come after H, which I can probably figure out on my own)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With such a small range you could just iterate the move_order and check if each element exists in the allowed moves

```
def start():
    move_order=[c for c in raw_input("Enter your moves: ")]
    moves = ['A','D','S','C','H']
    for c in move_order:
        if c not in moves:
            print "That's not a proper move!"
            return start()
```

Edit: Solution taking into account suggestions in comments

```
def start():
move_order=list(input("Enter your moves: "))
    while set(move_order) - set('ADSCH'):
        for x in set(move_order) - set('ADSCH'):
          move_order = [input("%s is not a vaild move, please enter another move" % x) if i==x else i for i in move_order]
    Print "Player ready" #Rest of program..
```

If I understand your question, i don't think split is doing what you think it is. It is not splitting each character of the string entered by the user into an array.

Comment: Oh it's not? Hahaha of course I'd screw that up :P uhhh how would I do that then (sorry if the comments aren't a place to ask more questions)? I just want each letter they put it to be added to the list. Would I use append or something?

Comment: I have given an example of one way to do it in my code above

Comment: Oh comments can only be edited for five minutes apparently :P I did like your code shows and got rid of the split, thank you!

Comment: It depends how you want the user to enter the moves. In my example, I went with the format of the original code and got the user to enter all moves at once.
If you wanted to use append, you could repeatedly ask the user to enter a single move until the combination was complete?

Comment: Do you really want to return a recursive call to start at the first non-move and skip any subsequent valid moves?

Comment: Ideally no, but seeing as this wasn't OPs question, I left it as it was.

Comment: I'd recommend `move_order = list(raw_input("Enter your moves: "))` and `if set(move_order) - set('ADSCH'):`. And I think `return start()` should be fixed even though it wasn't specifically mentioned.

Comment: Well see the way this is going to work, each player inputs 7 moves at once (it's a unique game >_>)  and each player's seven moves are compared against eachother. Like A is for attack and D is for defense, so I need to check the whole move list for errors before letting the other player give their moves. Your code earlier was very helpful, I've got it to check all the errors now (no c after h, no more or less than 7 moves...)

Comment: The only thing is that if like the user gives input AAAAAAR, it will print "Player 1 ready to go!" six times and then say "invalid move!" So I have to get it to do this check seven times and then move to the next step, but I don't know how to do that either :P

Comment: Not if you put "Player one ready to go" outside the loop. Have updated to once again to accommodate for this

Answer (score 1):

There're many ways to match 'ADSCH'
You can use `raw_input().upper()` to get rid of `'adsch'`

use `re`: don't do split before

```
def start():
    movement = raw_input("Enter your moves: ").upper()
    if re.match('^[ADSCH\s]*$', movement):
        # it's a legal input
```

use `str.strip`

```
if movement.strip(' ADSCH') == '':
    # it's a legal input
```

use `all` with `move_order` list(works with string either):

```
def start():
    move_order=[raw_input("Enter your moves: ").upper().split()]
    if all((x in 'ADSCH' for x in move_order)):
        # it's a legal input
```

use `any` with `move_order` list(works with string either):

```
if any((x not in 'ADSCH' for x in move_order)):
    # it's an illegal input
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python but you could do something like this:

```
for c in move_order:
if (c == 'A' or c == 'D' c == 'S' or c == 'C' or c == 'H'):
[do something with the character]
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing with the characters afterwards? There might not be any need to even have this step. Design it so that when you're doing the actions for the moves, you don't/can't do any invalid ones.

```
def move_left():
    print "Moving left"

def move_down():
    print "moving down"

#...etc

def invalid_move():
    print "invalid move"

# This dictionary connects move command letters
# with the functions above that do the moving
move_funcs = {
    'A': move_left,
    'S': move_down,
    'D': move_right,
    'C': wtf_keyboard_layout,
    'H': do_H_thing
}

moves = raw_input("Enter your moves: ")
for move in moves.upper():

    # this gets the right function for the move, 
    # e.g. A gets move_left
    # but any character not there gets invalid_move
    move_func = move_funcs.get(move, invalid_move)
    move_func()
```